# Getting a Class from another project programatically

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to access a class which is present in another project . For that i use java reflections,but first i need to get the class object which is in another project.I want to get it programatically.I can do that like right click on my project then go to build configure path and then to project tab and add project.I want to do it programmatically .How can i do that?Help

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "get it programmatically?"  If you want access to the class without adding the other project, you can add the classes directory of the other project to your build path, or make a jar as gurukulki suggests.  If you want to access a class not in your classpath at all, follow saugata's suggestion and create a custom class loader.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom class loader.

[tutorial link1](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18345.html)

[tutorial link 2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.142/html/id1100.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by creating a jar of the dependent project and adding it to class path before you run your application.

Answer (score 0):

It seams you are working in eclipse and want do use the classes from projet B in projet A, is it so?
If so you could specify in eclipse that project A depends from project B by adding the project in the 'java build properties'.
Do get the right answer, you ask to be more specific in your question like Steven wrote.